# Why my json.dumps not convert quote value to my browser?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to send my data from backend to django template here is my `views.py`:

```
def labels_chart(values):
    for i in sorted_by_size[:5]:
        values.append(i['forks'])
    return values

print(labels_chart(values))

chart_data = {
    'y': json.dumps(labels_chart(values)),
}
return render(req, 'index.html', chart_data)
```

Here is my templates `index.html`:

```
 <script>
        var x = "{{y}}"
        console.log(x)
</script>
```

When I `print(labels_chart(values))` it appear data : `['hello', 'wassup']` in my terminal but it showing like this `&quot;hello&quot;,&quot;wassup&quot;` in my browser.

Comment: the issue should be caused by the double quotes in `{{y}}`, so change `var x = "{{y}}"` to **var x = ` {{y}} `**  (assumed {{y}} doesn't have any character=\`)

Comment: It still not console.log anything

Comment: Oh I got it! But some how it showing this ```&quot;hello&quot;,&quot;wassup&quot;```

Comment: Use the `| safe` filter: **var x = `{{ y | safe }}`**

Comment: Nevertheless, please note that you need to have some considerations when using the `| safe` filter. More info about it: https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/18/safely-including-data-for-javascript-in-a-django-template/